# linq: Convert IEnumable<double> to IEnumable<string> using helper method

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable<double> I want to convert to an IEnumerable<string>. <del>The problem is the code below throws an argument null exception on the select statement.</del> What am I doing wrong?

> The actual problem occurs when I try
>   to iterate through the returned
>   IEnumerable<string>. I get an
>   InvalidCastException. I see in the
>   debuger that strings =
>   {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<double,string>}

```
  private IEnumerable<string> ConvertToString(IEnumerable<double> doubles)
  {
     IEnumerable<string> strings = null;

     if (doubles != null)
        strings = doubles.Select(d => ConvertToString(d));

     return strings;
  }


  private string ConvertToString(double d)
  {
     return string.Format("{0:0.00}", d);
  }
```

Okay, I solved my problem. This Linq delayed execution makes debugging tricky. I actually have a call upstream causing the problem.

```
ICollection<float> floats; //pretend it holds valid data
ConvertToString(floats.Cast<double>()) //<---This is naughty
```

Comment: The code as-is shouldn't throw any ArgumentNullException. `d` cannot be null, because it's a value type; and `doubles` cannot be null, because you check for that. Can you add a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried your code and I do not get an error.

That implies that you are passing a null `IEnumerable<double>` into your method.

P.s.
You can shorten your method to this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ConvertToString(IEnumerable<double> doubles)
{
   return doubles.Select(ConvertToString);
}
```

Comment: Matt you are correct. The code example above should work. The actual exception is caused up stream in my code, and doesn't throw until I loop through the IEnumarable<double>

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
doubles.Select(d => d.ToString("0.00"));
```

Or for some real fun that should accomodate your business logic:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ConvertToString(IEnumerable<double> doubles, Func<string, double> convertToString)
{
    return doubles.Select(d => convertToString(d))
}

ConvertToString(doubles, d => d.ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: The business logic is actually more complicated, I just left it simple for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the conversion this way:

```
ver strings = doubles.Select(d => string.Format("{0:0.00}", d));
```